Rust slice.windows() iterator equivalent
I want to iterate over some elements with an iterator and perform on such elements operations which need to read previous or following values from the iterable.
When using slices I learned that I can use slice.windows() but I would like to do that with an iterator without calling collect() in order not to use space.
let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let foo = my_vec.windows(3); // [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]
let bar = my_vec.iter(); //.windows(3) -> Iter<_, [i32; 3]>

I can for sure imagine a solution where I wrap the iterator in a custom type, call next() a couple of times and keep the references to the previous values but I was wondering if there is a clean way to do this leveraging the language library.

.windows returns an Iterator, you don't need to .collect(). Eg.: [1,2,3,4,5].windows(3).for_each(|w| println!("{:?}", w)); You clould improve your question by describing what exactly you want to do with these windows.

Take it as a given that I am starting from an iterator not from a slice so I cannot call windows on the iterator. @aedm

If I understand well, this can be done easily with itertools crate: https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows

"I can for sure imagine a solution where I wrap the iterator in a custom type, call next() a couple of times and keep the references to the previous values" it does not actually work, because you need somewhere to stash the elements you're referencing, and the windows can be kept forever, so your stash has to live just as long, hence you end up with... a vector storing all your elements, which is basically what the stdlib asks. One alternative is to limit windowing over copy/clone like itertools.

You can feed elements into a bounded deque, but that does not work as a "normal" Iterator adapter (implementing Iterator itself) as the deque would have to be lent to the user for just the duration of an iteration. That requires either GATs, or using a higher-order function to drive the iteration.

I am checking and will take me a while but I think the itertools create will do

A LendingIterator could store the items but has severe limitations on iterating namely separate items can't coxist.
